# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, winterbash, hats

[The Winter Bash is back!](https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) From 19 December 2016 - 8 January 2017, Stack Exchange will be running Winter Bash 2016. Like in the past, participating in Winter Bash will mean that users here can earn "hats" for their gravatars by doing certain stuff, and there'll be a leaderboard to see who is getting the most hats across the network. Individual users, of course, will be able to opt out.

Do we want to participate in hats this year? This year, it's an opt-out program. I must confirm with the CM team by 13 December if we don't want hats.

Questions? Comments?

Comment: Are there any sites that actually reject hats?  Grinch.SE?

Comment: Do I get a special hat for wanting hats?

Comment: Any chance of getting a summer bash next year for those of us who live in the southern hemisphere?

Comment: I'll gladly wear an "I won't wear hats" hat.  They're a little on the lame side.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No questions. Give us our hats.

Comment: I must haz hats.

Answer (score 10):

I don't care as long as individual opt-out is available.

Comment: There is always an individual opt-out